# How to get terminal nodes for a new observation from an rpart object?

Tags: r, rpart

Say I have

```
head(kyphosis)
inTrain <- sample(1:nrow(kyphosis), 45, replace = F)
TRAIN_KYPHOSIS <- kyphosis[inTrain,]
TEST_KYPHOSIS <- kyphosis[-inTrain,]

(kyph_tree <- rpart(Number ~ ., data = TRAIN_KYPHOSIS))
```

How to get the terminal node from the fitted object for each observation in `TEST_KYPHOSIS`?

How do I get a summary, such as the deviance and the predicted value from the terminal node which each test observation maps to?

Answer (score 8):

`rpart` actually has this functionality but it's not exposed (strangely enough, it's a rather obvious requirement).

```
predict_nodes <-
    function (object, newdata, na.action = na.pass) {
        where <-
            if (missing(newdata)) 
                object$where
            else {
                if (is.null(attr(newdata, "terms"))) {
                    Terms <- delete.response(object$terms)
                    newdata <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, 
                                           xlev = attr(object, "xlevels"))
                    if (!is.null(cl <- attr(Terms, "dataClasses"))) 
                        .checkMFClasses(cl, newdata, TRUE)
                }
                rpart:::pred.rpart(object, rpart:::rpart.matrix(newdata))
            }
        as.integer(row.names(object$frame))[where]
    }
```

And then:

```
> predict_nodes(kyph_tree, TEST_KYPHOSIS)
 [1] 5 3 4 3 3 5 5 3 3 3 3 5 5 4 3 5 4 3 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 5 3 4 4 3 5 3 5 5 5
```

Comment: Why does `rpart:::pred.rpart(object, rpart:::rpart.matrix(newdata))` lead to a predicted node?

Comment: @goldisfine, because this is how  rpart computes the predicted nodes internally. This functinallity is used internally, but not exposed.

Comment: @VitoshKa Thank for posting solution. This is such a fundamental part of tree! It is almost unusable without this part.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to convert the `rpart` object to an object of class `party` from the `partykit` package. That provides a general toolkit for dealing with recursive partytions. The conversion is simple:

```
library("partykit")
(kyph_party <- as.party(kyph_tree))

Model formula:
Number ~ Kyphosis + Age + Start

Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] Start >= 15.5: 2.933 (n = 15, err = 10.9)
|   [3] Start < 15.5
|   |   [4] Age >= 112.5: 3.714 (n = 14, err = 18.9)
|   |   [5] Age < 112.5: 5.125 (n = 16, err = 29.8)

Number of inner nodes:    2
Number of terminal nodes: 3
```

(For exact reproducibility run the code from your question with `set.seed(1)` prior to running my code.)

For objects of this class there are somewhat more flexible methods for `plot()`, `predict()`, `fitted()`, etc. For example, `plot(kyph_party)` yields a more informative display than the default `plot(kyph_tree)`. The `fitted()` method extracts a two-column `data.frame` with the fitted node numbers and the observed responses on the training data.

```
kyph_fit <- fitted(kyph_party)
head(kyph_fit, 3)

  (fitted) (response)
1        5          6
2        2          2
3        4          3
```

With this you can easily compute any quantity you are interested in, e.g., the means, median, or residual sums of squares within each node.

```
tapply(kyph_fit[,2], kyph_fit[,1], mean)

       2        4        5 
2.933333 3.714286 5.125000 

tapply(kyph_fit[,2], kyph_fit[,1], median)

2 4 5 
3 4 5 

tapply(kyph_fit[,2], kyph_fit[,1], function(x) sum((x - mean(x))^2))

       2        4        5 
10.93333 18.85714 29.75000
```

Instead of the simple `tapply()` you can use any other function of your choice to compute the tables of grouped statistics.

Now to learn which observation from the test data `TEST_KYPHOSIS` to which node in the tree you can simply use the `predict(..., type = "node")` method:

```
kyph_pred <- predict(kyph_party, newdata = TEST_KYPHOSIS, type = "node")
head(kyph_pred)

 2  3  4  6  7 10 
 4  4  5  2  2  5
```

Comment: You solution yields the same result as `kyph_tree$where` and it is different from what results obtained with VitoshKa solution below.

Comment: The `predict_nodes()` solution by VitoshKa and the `predict(..., type = "node")` solution in `partykit` do not yield exactly the same _labels_ because the node IDs are assigned a bit differently. But the information is in fact equivalent. Check out: `table(predict_nodes(kyph_tree, TEST_KYPHOSIS), predict(kyph_party, newdata = TEST_KYPHOSIS, type = "node"))`. It may not be diagnoal due to the different labels but there is a 1:1 match. But this is because `partykit` provides general solutions for recursive partitining which are not specific to `rpart`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am struggling to understand what `kyph_tree$where` returns. It does not look like it returns terminal node label

Comment: It's, in fact, simply the terminal node label/ID as on the training data `TRAIN_KYPHOSIS` For example, check out, `table(kyph_tree$where)`. If you compare that with `table(fitted(kyph_party)[,1])` or `table(predict(kyph_party, type = "node"))` you will see the same absolute frequencies but possibly different labels (depending on the structure of the tree).

Comment: thank you again. I am not sure I understand what you mean by label/ID. `unique(kyph_tree$where)` returns `3,7,5,6`, but if you look at resulting tree the terminal nodes are: `4, 10, 11, 3'. I used 'fancyRpartPlot(kyph_tree)' to plot the tree.

Comment: Good point. The IDs in `$where` pertain to rows in `$frame`, i.e., are not the same labels used in printing/plotting but correspond to IDs in a summary table. If you use the row names from that summary table you get the same labels used in printing/plotting: `table(as.numeric(rownames(kyph_tree$frame))[kyph_tree$where])`.