# Add or subtract values from decision tree leaves

Tags: r, rpart

How to subtract a value from the predicted value in a models decision tree? I'm using `rpart` to create a model of housing prices and it produces a predicted price at every node/leaf:

[image: Housing Prices]

Ideally, I would like to perform these operations:

1. retrieve the row names for the observations that are in the nodes at the bottom
2. calculate the mean value and then subtract the mean *in* the model. The reason is that I would like to get the difference in actual price in the bottom nodes and not just the predicted price.

My training data looks something like this (from the [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data)):

```
Id, LivingArea, GarageArea,..., SalePrice  
1, 1200, 500, ..., 50 000  
2, 500, 1500, ..., 150 000
```

Comment: It looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304349/how-to-get-terminal-nodes-for-a-new-observation-from-an-rpart-object/29328690#29328690) shows how to do something very similar.

Comment: I'm looking at the party package but I'm not seeing how I can use it to create the plot that I want.
I'm quite new to R so maybe I'm missing something.